# Stroustrup: C++ implementation of reserve()

Tags: c++

I dont understand the code given in Bjarne Stroustrup - Programming Chapter 19.5.6 RAII for vector:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
struct vector_base {
  A alloc;
  T* elem;
  int sz;
  int space;
  vector_base(const A& a, int n) : alloc{a}, elem{alloc.allocate(n)}, sz{n}, space{n}{}
  ~vector_base() {alloc.deallocate(elem,space);}
}

//--------- vector class ------------
template<typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
class vector : private vector_base<T,A> {
   // ...
};

//--------- vector reserve ------------
template<typename T, typename A>
void vector<T,A>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
  if (newalloc <= this->space) return;
  vector_base<T,A> b(this->alloc,newalloc);
  uninitialized_copy(b.elem, &b.elem[this->sz], this->elem);
  for(int i=0; i<this->sz; ++i)
     this->alloc.destroy(&this->elem[i]);
  swap<vector_base<T,A>>(*this,b);
}
```

1) I don't understand what is the need to pass the allocator along to the new `vector_base` `object b`. The `vector_base` has its own allocator, why does the constructor need `this->alloc`?

2) I don't understand the `uninitialized_copy` line. It looks like we copy from `b` to `this->elem`. It should be the other way around. Is that just a mistake in the book, or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new `vector` needs to use the same allocator as the existing `vector`, i.e., `this->alloc` to make sure the reallocated memory comes from the same allocation area. If different allocators were used `swap()` on the last line would exchange the memory in the `vector` to point to memory allocated from a different allocator than that used to release the memory later.

The use of `std::uninitialized_copy()` is indeed wrong: it would copy from the newly created, uninitialised memory to the original values. Assuming the source and destination are appropriately put in place there is another error: if the memory of the existing `vector` is fully used, the expression `&this->elem[this->sz]` forms a reference to an object past the last element. The expression should rather read `this->elem + this->sz`. That is, the initialisation should be

```
uninitialized_copy(this->elem, this->elem + this->sz,
                   b.elem);
```